# Getting Connection Timeout while using HTTP POST

Tags: java

I am trying to do a HTTP POST to URL from my Java client code. Its a standard plain Standalone java class But i am repeteadly getting the following error. i searched on the net but could not find any proper solution for the same. i have given all the information below.

Below is the error that i am getting.

```
PostMethod filePost = new PostMethod(targetURL); 

filePost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(HttpMethodParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);

Part[] parts = {new FilePart(targetFile.getName(), targetFile)};

filePost.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, filePost.getParams()));

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 

client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(8000); 

int status = client.executeMethod(filePost)
```

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

```
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:185)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
```

Can you please what is wrong with code and why i am getting this connection timeout everytime.
Its very badly affetcing my work so can you guys help me in finding a soluton for this issue.

Thanks
Vikeng21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timeout generally is seen when you did not configure you server properly (protocol/IP/port). Are you able to make the request from browser ? Are there any firewall problems ?

Comment: Hi Chris.as you told when i try to make a request to the url from the browser i get page not found error. i tried with the following exmple url http://test.xyzpqr.com. what does it mean is the error that i am getting because of this issue

Comment: This means that you server is not up and running. You should fix your server code before you send requests from the client.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Then it means that the server is down or not responding. The behaviour is very unique as the HTTP PUT to the same server does not provide any error and the file gets written to outputstream. any ideas on this wierd behaviour.

Comment: The functionality is working fine. The problem was that there was very less documentation on the servlet that was handling the request for both the HTTP PUT/POST. The servlet was expecting certain headers in the request which i set manually before upload and everything started working as expected.